# How To Parse This Content Into Friendly URLS

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing, dom

Im using simple php dom parser to get a tables td contents which I am outputting as plaintext and comes out like this:

```
<p>              Graphic Artist / Designer<br />
              $23,755 &#8211; $55,335              <br />              Sales Associate<br />
              $15,577 &#8211; $56,290              <br />              Film / Video Editor<br />
              $24,184 &#8211; $94,493              </p>
```

What I would like to do is take the above, and turn it into this:

```
<a href="/graphic-artist-designer">Graphic Artist / Designer</a>
    $23,755 – $55,335 <br />
<a href="/sales-associate">Sales Associate</a><br />
    $15,577 – $56,290 <br />
<a href="/film-video-editor">Film / Video Editor</a><br />
    $24,184 – $94,493 <br />
```

So you can see im taking the job name, lowering casing all of it, and replacing spaces and slashes with a dash to use as the URL.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to lowercase and then eliminate non-word characters this way:

```
$slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/', '-', strtolower($name));
```

If you have trouble intgrating this into your solution, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Thanks this works almost flawlessly except its adding a dash to the beginning and end of each job url like so: <a href="/-graphic-artist-designer-">

Comment: I guess you have to remove the whitespaces. Use trim(strtolower($name)), or trim(preg_replace(...),'-')
Preferably the first :)